# Are there any adverse effects if setImmediate is used intensively?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My question is, can the use intensive of setimmediate affect negatively the performance?
I have made a simplified example code of the algorithm. A code similar to this will be executed every time a http request is received.

```
const wrapper = (next, handler) => {
    const val = handler(next)
    console.log('exec', handler.name)
    if (val !== undefined) {
        console.log(val)
    }
}

const dispatch = (i, ...handlers) => {
    const handler = handlers[i]
    const next = () => {
        dispatch(++i, ...handlers)
    }

    wrapper(next, handler)
    // setImmediate(wrapper, next, handler)
}

const pass = (next) => {
    next()
}

const greet = () => {
    return 'hello'
}

dispatch(0, pass, greet)


/**
output whiout setImmediate:
exec greet
hello
exec pass

output whit setImmediate:
exec pass
exec greet
hello
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

It likely won't, but measuring the impact by running benchmarks and load tests would be the best way to confirm since there could be some unexpected impact.